# EntityDataSource GROUPBY problem

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

can anyone explain why this code is causing an error?

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="bookingModel.bookingEntities" 
    EntitySetName="t_sessionSet" 
    Select="it.[t_session_id], it.[t_session_datetime], it.[t_session_location], it.[t_session_active], it.[t_session_notes], it.[t_session_trainer]"
    GroupBy="it.[t_session_datetime]" >
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

The error I get is: "The identifier 'it' is not valid because it is not contained either in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Select` clause you cannot use properties which you don't use in the `GroupBy` clause. You either need to omit all other properties except for `t_session_datetime` from the Select clause or add them to the GroupBy clause or apply aggregate function - for instance `Count`, `Min`, `Max`, `Sum`, etc. to them. Your Select clause could then look like:

```
Select="Min(it.[t_session_id]) AS MinId,
    it.[t_session_datetime],
    Min(it.[t_session_location]) AS Location,
    Min(it.[t_session_active]) AS Active,
    Min(it.[t_session_notes]) AS Notes,
    Min(it.[t_session_trainer]) AS Trainer"
```

I am not sure if this will work for `Active` if that is a boolean property. You can find a list of aggregate functions which are available in Entity SQL [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738514.aspx).

Comment: Thank you - it's obvious now! I think I was stumped by the error message about 'it' which didn't make sense. Normally, SQL produces a different error for something like this I think.